# Generating Tiles for Non Geographic Datasets

Tags: data, graph, tiling

Excuse my ignorance if this exists. I don't think I've seen a website ever using something like this.

Have tools been developed that use general tiling methodology to implement non-geographical data sets?

A line graph for instance - say, stock price, climate, or, seismographs? If the measurement frequency is high, these data sets can become extremely dense. Which can be bandwidth intensive when transferring to the client.

Tools like [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) and Tile Map Services have solved this for cartographers. You feed these programs data & styles, and they render and serve thousands (millions) of PNGs, which eventually get stitched together on a web slippy map.

This would effectively be a replacement for something like [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), or [DyGraphs](http://dygraphs.com/).

What I'd love is a command line tool that I feed SQL, colors, fonts, zoom levels, etc, and it generates all graph tiles at all desired zoom levels.

Comment: I cannot see a GIS component to your question so I think it would be better asked at Super User or Stack Overflow rather than here at GIS Stack Exchange.

Comment: I would look at a wavelet based solution on other sites. Tiles are for images, so you would need to convert your graph to an image (not necessary georeferenced) in order to use tiling.